# Is there an Android open source alarm clock? I want to log whether or not I press snooze

Tags: alarm

I want to add custom features to an alarm clock in a way that it logs whether or not I press snooze every day.
Is there a good open source alarm clock that I could use as a basis?

Comment: I am interested, where is the modified code? Have you released the modified app on the Android Market? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend the standard android clock as a basis for this: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/DeskClock.git;a=summary

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but there's another called Alarm Klock that is open source as well.. Apache2 license.
https://code.google.com/p/kraigsandroid/